# SQL injection on PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, sql-injection

My clienet(android) sends user details in the user form and my servlet just enters those details into to the database(postgre sql). I tried to give to do a sql injection attack by giving `;DELETE FROM tbl_name;` in the username field.
But postgresql just treats it as a value and enters it as the username. How do I do the SQLINjection attack. (I have not done any sort of checking in the postgre sql or the servlet).
Does it mean that postgresql is SQLInjection attack resistant? 
I am using the following statements to insert the data:

```
String insert ="insert into userdetail(username,id,sno) values('"+username+"','"+userid+"','"+no+"')";
                   Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                    stmt.executeUpdate(insert);
```

The username contains `;DELETE FROM userdetail;`.
I have tried the following also:

```
');DELETE FROM userdetail;
```

But it fives the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: unterminat
ed quoted string at or near "');"
  Position: 1
```

I have also tried this:

```
','',');DELETE FROM userdetail;
```

This gives the following error:

```
17:36:46,828 INFO  [STDOUT] org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: unterminat
ed quoted string at or near "''');"
  Position: 38
```

but does not delete the records of the table. How do I make it delete the tables records?

Comment: Postgresql is not SQLInjection resistant, you are probably not using the single quote (') properly. Could you please the exact string you are trying and the query it is building to insert in the database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key trick is that the complete statement string must

- do something *innovative*
- be still valid SQL

So far the answers have omitted the second part. But an invalid SQL statement will abort the transaction and hence most likely does nothing at all. If you set `autoCommit` to `true` that attack may be easier.

But this string should to the trick in a "clean" way:

```
foo', '42', '42'); delete from userdetail; --
```

Note: The resulting string is this (line breaks only for better reading):

```
insert into userdetail(username,id,sno) values('foo', '42', '42'); 
delete from userdetail; 
-- ','21','21')
```

Both the `INSERT` part is complete and correct (assuming no unique index collisions of course) and also the `DELETE` is correct. The potentially offending rest is masked by the trailing SQL comment `--`.

Comment: :The SQL comments did the trick. Without the comments it gives give unterminated quoted string error.

Comment: @user1139023: The SQL comment is indeed the central point in "be still valid SQL".

Answer (score 2):

<strike>hat type of attack that you are describing - even if you get the use of single quotes "correct" - will not work with PostgreSQL
It does not work because the JDBC driver does not allow to run more than one statement in a single `Statement.execute()` call. 
It will throw an error ("invalid character" pointing to the ;)</strike>
(Sorry, this is only true for Oracle)

There are other scenarios that would work with a badly written application.

Assuming the application is checking the username/password like this (note that this is a very simplified example!)

```
String sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE username = '";
sql += username;
sql += "' AND password = '";
sql += pwd;
sql += "'"
```

then a possible attack could be to enter the value:

```
' or 1=1 or '' = '
```

into the password field.

This would wind up with the following generated SQL

```
SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE username = 'arthur' 
AND password = '' or 1=1 or ''=''
```

Which would always be true and one could login without a password.

Comment: You can more than one single statement in jdbc. My application requires that the userdetails be inserted into two tables. I do that By Using a single executeUpdate statement. The string inside passed as the argument to the executeUpdate statement contains two insert statements seperated by ';'.

Comment: @user1139023: hmm, interesting. I'm pretty sure I have seen this fail with Postgres. But maybe this was Oracle after all. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Try `', '', '');DELETE FROM tbl_name;` to delete your table.

In simplest case, you can give `'` as user name and your server should give you an error.

Besides, there is no SQL injection resistant database because SQL injection happens because of poorly coded server-side (CGI) script and not because of database weaknesses.

Comment: I will try that and let you know.

Comment: comma is not allowed in any of the fields in my app. Can I remove the comma's and try it.

Comment: practically, you can. But be wary that the server might give an error that your INSERT statement is invalid which refers to a successful SQL injection.

Comment: I tried '''');DELETE FROM userdetail; .It still takes it as a value and inserts '''');DELETE FROM userdetail; as the username.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ', '', '');DELETE FROM tbl_name; one more Single quote before the bracket. Because there are three columns in the table.